# How to visualize the content of an array graphically in MPLABx

Tags: arrays, graph, mplab

I am using the MPLABX IDE v.5.35. I also downloaded DMCI plugin, thinking that can show the content of an array. I am using the new PICkit4. I also own an old RealIce.

I read many other posts and developer's forums, I don't seem to find any solution, how to debug an application array content. I am receiving a digital audio from a microphone and wish to visualize the received data array (unsigned int audio.buffer[1000]).

I know I can export it into cvs file and show it in Excel or similar. Is there an easy way to show it directly in MPLABX? Is the DMCI the tool for it (I cannot show there any data)?

UPDATE: Now I tried both Real Ice and PicKit4, same thing, no show on the graph.

UPDATE 2: Now I see global variables? It seems that DMCI will not show global variables defined in structures??

I can see:

```
unsigned int audio_counter; // global variable
```

I cannot see any of these variables :(

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned int    buffer[AUDIO_BUFFER_SIZE];      ///< collecting audio samples
    unsigned int    skip_countdown;                 ///< skipping samples, only store a value when the counter == 0                   
    unsigned int *  head_ptr;                       ///< circular buffer pointer
    unsigned int *  tail_ptr;                       ///< circular buffer pointer
    unsigned int    i;
    bool            overflowed;                     ///< flag indicating data overflowed the buffer
} audio_struct;
```

Comment: May have a look here:https://microchipdeveloper.com/mplabx:dmci-videos

Comment: I looked at both of those before. They do not show array content in graph, but one variable changing in time. I am trying to visualize an existing array data collection, stationary way, in MPLAB.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can call this a solution: for the debugging purposes, I defined a simple global variable array instead of the 'nicer' definition in the structure. It works with both PicKit4 and RealICE.

Then, and only then, the graph of my audio recording shows up (1000 samples from the digital microphone, word "Hey!" and a clap). Still, if anyone knows how to avoid this patch, it would be great!

[image]